# Send datetime from iPhone app to a webservice

Tags: c#, ios, json, nsdate, nsdateformatter

From iPhone application, I have to send date as a parameter to a webservice method where server parsing logic is implemented with C#, .NET and JSON.

In my iPhone application I am formatting the date as:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
NSString *myDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:SentOn];
```

I am getting the error:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type  DashboardDataContract.Contracts.DashboardInputParams. DateTime content '2013-04-04T12:00:00Z' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON.'.

I tried different formatting of dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the JSON.Net library will emit all dates using the ISO Date format e.g `"2012-05-09T00:00:00Z"`, but Microsoft’s JSON formatter for date will emit using Microsoft’s own format `“/Date(xxxxxxxxxxxx)/”`

You can try this:

```
unsigned long long time=(([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])*1000);
NSString* dateTimeTosend= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%lld)/",time];
```

Comment: If you want to add the time zone you need the format to be /Date(xxxxxxxxxxxx+yyyy)/ where yyyy is the time zone for example:/Date(12345678954+0000)/

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to send NSDate to server is to get the [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp). You can basically get it with

```
NSTimeInterval timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeInvervalSince1970];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category method in `NSDate`

```
- (NSString *)jsonDateString
{
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [self timeIntervalSince1970];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%.0f+0000)/",seconds*1000];

}
```